# Generic type class name in attribute

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

i have a base controller class and inside this i have create, delete and getbyid methods. 
Please look at the code

```
 public abstract class BaseControllerWithAuthorization<TEntity, TCreateRequest, TResponse, TManager, TKey> : Controller
    where TEntity : BaseModel<TKey>
    where TManager : IBusinessManager<TEntity, TCreateRequest, TKey>
{
    protected readonly TManager Manager;
    protected readonly ILocalizationService LocalizationService;
    protected readonly ILogger<Controller> Logger;
    protected readonly IMapper Mapper;

    protected BaseControllerWithAuthorization(TManager manager, ILocalizationService localizationService, ILogger<Controller> logger, IMapper mapper)
    {
        Manager = manager;
        LocalizationService = localizationService;
        Logger = logger;
        Mapper = mapper;
    }

    [Route("create")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Permission(nameof(TEntity), Crud.Create)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] TCreateRequest request)
    {
        var result = await Manager.CreateAsync(request);
        return Ok(new ApiResponse(LocalizationService, Logger).Ok(Mapper.Map<TEntity, TResponse>(result)));
    }

    [Route("delete/{id}")]
    [HttpDelete]
    [Permission(nameof(TEntity), Crud.Delete)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(TKey id)
    {
        await Manager.DeleteAsync(id);
        return Ok(new ApiResponse(LocalizationService, Logger).Ok(true));
    }

    [Route("get/id/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Permission(nameof(TEntity), Crud.Select)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(TKey id)
    {
        var result = await Manager.GetByIdAsync(id);
        return Ok(new ApiResponse(LocalizationService, Logger).Ok(Mapper.Map<TEntity, TResponse>(result)));
    }
}
```

I have to pass TEntity class name to the PermissionAttribute for doing some authorization operations but unfortunately nameof(TEntity) code is not working and gives me "TEntity" string definition instead of "Customer" (e.g)

If there is no way to pass class name string maybe you can show me another way to do authorization process. For this i sent also my PermissionAttribute class code

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class PermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Entity { get; set; }

    public Crud? Crud { get; set; }

    public PermissionAttribute(string entity, Crud crud) : base("Permission")
    {
        Entity = entity;
        Crud = crud;
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't think there's a mechanism to do what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to evaluate a `nameof` to get the actual type, since `nameof` is determined on compile time. It becomes a `string`, no matter what `T` ends up to be.

Since attributes can't be injected with the current instance, you are hitting a dead end. You might want to change your approach. Maybe message filters can help you out here.

Comment: Thank you so much i will look at message filters